# Implementation of MTA COM server

Tags: winapi, com, mta

I can't find any source code on the prerequisites of an MTA compliant COM. I tried changing the ThreadingModel registry key of my object from Apartment to Both, and it results in a crash when a secondary thread calls the method before any data is accessed.

If STA COMs require a message pump, what kind of plumbing code do MTA COM objects require?

Comment: What is the call stack of the crash?

Comment: There is no boiler-plate code *ever* for a class that's guaranteed thread-safe.  That needs to be done the hard way, use locking primitives to ensure that a method of your COM server can be called by an arbitrary thread at an arbitrary time and cannot corrupt the state of your object.

Comment: @VáclavZeman: it's complicated, as they say. The COM itself has been built using an obscure language called Clarion, which has no ability to debug COMs. The .NET wrapper does not go that far.

Comment: @HansPassant: like I said, it crashes **before it even touches anything** and there are mutexes and semaphores everywhere.

Comment: Nevermind. The issue was Clarion-specific need to re-link new threads since even primitives in their runtime library involve thread specific memory allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that there is anything special about MTA, except that you need to use synchronization primitives like mutexes to synchronize access to your internal structures. Does the ["Multithreaded Apartments"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) not give you all that you need?

Quoting from the documentation, emphasis is mine:

> Because calls to objects are not serialized in any way, multithreaded object concurrency offers the highest performance and takes the best advantage of multiprocessor hardware for cross-thread, cross-process, and cross-machine calling. This means, however, *that the code for objects must provide synchronization in their interface implementations, typically through the use of synchronization primitives such as event objects, critical sections, mutexes, or semaphores*, which are described later in this section. In addition, because the object doesn't control the lifetime of the threads that are accessing it, no thread-specific state may be stored in the object (in thread local storage).